# Can't include wdm.h and ntifs.h in the same file

Tags: c++, wdk

My compiler (vs2012) refuse to compile the following lines of code. He postes redefintion of Symbols for PEPROCESS and PETHREAD. How can i workaround this? And why can't i use both headers?

```
 #include <wdm.h>
 #include <Ntifs.h>

double hal_datetime_utc_now()
{
   LARGE_INTEGER gmtTime;
   KeQuerySystemTime(&gmtTime);

   ULONG utc_now;
   RtlTimeToSecondsSince1970(&gmtTime, &utc_now);
   return (double)utc_now;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. In my scenario, i can remove the wdm.h. Because KeQuerySystemTime is also included in ntifs.h. So i can simply remove wdm.h.

EDIT: typo: replace wdm.h with ntifs.h

Comment: You said 'wdm.h' twice. Did you mean 'remove Ntifs.h' or 'also included in Ntifs'?

Answer (score 0):

In case ntifs.h is nonetheless needed, switching the order and including ntifs.h before wdm.h may also work.